# Rails 3: Add roles to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm using cancan as my authorization engine.

I already have the roles in user:

```
  ROLES = %w[admin normal author corp]
```

I also have methods to add and check roles:

```
#cancan
  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def is?(role)
    roles.include?(role.to_s)
  end
```

And I have `#  roles_mask           :integer` in the User model.

However, I want to have a `after_save :add_normal_role` which assigns the normal role to the user.

Basically, I'm not being able (don't know) how to assign roles to each user.

This is what I have, which doesn't work:

```
private

  def add_normal_role
    self.roles=(ROLES[1])
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using a before_create callback ensuring the user has a normal role.

The problem with your current callback is since it's an after_save, your modifications aren't saved by default. (Saving in an after_save callback is a bad idea leading to infinite loops...) You could also use a before_save callback (with the same code you already have), which will also work.

However, since you really only need to add a normal role when the object is created (and not on every update), a before_create is better suited.

Comment: With that code, I have this error: undefined method `&' for "normal":String

Comment: Yes, I think you should have `self.roles=([ROLES[1]])` in your code (notice you're passing an array).